# Malloc a struct within a struct?

Tags: struct, malloc

I decided to use structs in this program to keep it organized so I now have a chain of structs. My question is if I must malloc a struct that is within another struct. For example:

```
typedef struct OnlineS {
struct BBSIS *bbsi;
struct BBVIS *bbvi;
struct VBVIS *vbvi;
} *OnlineP;

typedef struct BBSIS{
struct FirstFitS *ff;
struct BestFitS *bf;
struct NextFitS *nf;
int itemNum;
int binNum;
int binMin;
int binMax;
int *items;
}*BBSIP;
```

And so on, so would my declaration and mallocs look like?

```
OnlineP on = malloc(sizeof (struct OnlineS));
on->bbsi = malloc(sizeof (struct BBSIS));
on->bbsi->bf = malloc(sizeof (struct BestFitS));
on->bbsi->nf = malloc(sizeof (struct NextFitS));
on->bbsi->ff = malloc(sizeof (struct FirstFitS));
on->bbvi = malloc(sizeof (struct BBVIS));
on->bbvi->bf = malloc(sizeof (struct BestFitS));
//ETC
```

Comment: For the record, you really need to be checking the return of value of `malloc` for zero. Not doing so is a recipe for unreliability.

Answer (score 0):

If you use pointers to structs within a struct you must manage memory for that as well. (malloc/free)

If tou use structs within a struct you do not  manage memory for the internal structures. Since they are part of the outer struct there is no need to.

You use pointer to structs in your outer struc so you must use malloc and free.

First allocate memory for your outer struct, then set all pointers to the inner structs to null or allocate memory for it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no struct in your struct.

There is a *pointer* in your struct, and the memory for the pointer was allocated.

Consider the following construct:

```
typedef struct node {
   struct node* next;
}
```

(Which is very common - a linked list)

How many nodes should it allocate?

Comment: This is a binning application (HW) using multiple heuristic algorithms. There are multiple linked lists with a variable amount of  nodes in each heuristic (i.e BestFit), which I made into its own struct for organizational purposes. The number of nodes is being processed from an external text file (which is then properly malloced).

Comment: What I'm trying to say is: the compiler cannot automatically allocate this, as it might be self-referential.